# Compute Dot Product of Two Vectors

Tags: lambda, prolog

I'm supposed to create a predicate in prolog such that `iprod(List1, List2, Result)` takes two lists of equal length and each contain integers. The result is the dot product of the two vectors.

For example, `List1 = [1,2,3]`, `List2 = [4,5,6]`, then the result would be `1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6`. Also I'm not supposed to use the built-in dotproduct function.

My code so far:

```
iprod([],[], 0).
iprod([H1|List1], [H2|List2], Result is H1 * H2) :- iprod(List1, List2, Result).
```

Comment: So what's the question? Is it "will you do this homework for me"?

Comment: for guidelines on asking help with homework on SO, read ["How to ask and answer homework questions?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Let me rephrase this. The above is the problem question. I get up to the point where Result = ((0 is 2 * 4) is 1 * 3). Why won't Result be a actual number? Instead its giving me all the calculations?

Comment: You did not show code, so it's hard to imagine what causes the funny expression you've reported for Result.  Generally "=" will not evaluate an arithmetic expression, it will just unify as a term that arithmetic expression (formula), but predicate "is" will force the value of an arithmetic expression to be unified.  So I suspect you need to understand the different uses of "=" and "is" better.  The importance of showing your code in this case is to see whether you appreciate the recursive approach to solving problems in Prolog.  After all, the vectors/lists can apparently have any length.

Comment: Ok, i'll double check to make sure i understand the difference. 
Here's my code hope it makes sense.
iprod([],[], 0).
iprod([H1|List1], [H2|List2], Result is H1 * H2) :- iprod(List1, List2, Result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Prolog:

```
domains
  ilist=integer*

predicates
  iprod(ilist, ilist, integer, integer)

clauses
  iprod([], _, R, R).    
  iprod([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], A, R):-
    M = X * Y,
    Rnew = A + M,
    iprod(XS, Ys, Rnew, R).


goal
  iprod([1,2,3],[4,5,6], 0, R).
```

Results in `32`. Sorry, no other Prolog implementation is available at hand.

Comment: This is a good approach, and with minor changes can be turned into ISO Prolog:  
    iprod([ ],[ ],R,R).
    iprod([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],A,R) :-
        Anew is (X*Y) + A,
        iprod(Xs,Ys,Anew,R).
    iprod(Xvct,Yvct,DotP) :- iprod(Xvct,Yvct,0,DotP).

Perhaps a word of explanation about expanding from **iprod/3** to **iprod/4** would be helpful to a new Prolog programmer?

Answer (score 4):

Using SWI-Prolog:

```
?- use_module(library(lambda)).

?- maplist(\X^Y^Z^(Z=X*Y),[1,2,3],[4,5,6],Dots).
   Dots = [1*4,2*5,3*6].
?- maplist(\X^Y^Z^(Z is X*Y),[1,2,3],[4,5,6],Dots).
   Dots = [4,10,18].
```

Comment: You've produced the entry-by-entry products of two lists.  The dot product of two vectors (here represented by lists of equal length) is a single scalar (numeric value), the sum of the products you produced.

Comment: True, but the OP's difficulty lies in the understanding of syntactic unification vs. arithmetic evaluation.